# Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat, elastic-beats

### Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

Hello,

Something weird happend lately in my elasticsearch setup. Metricbeat index got replaced with a new name like the old one is like metricbeat.x.date, but now the index is showing as metricbeat. Version and when trying to visualize. I am getting the bellow error.

Error:

```
[esaggs] > Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [host.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"metricbeat-7.2.1","node":"iD4ffU_sR2-uLU_SP01Ukw","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [host.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [host.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [host.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}}},"status":400}
```

Tried solutions:

Provided the following in console.

```
PUT my_index/_doc/host.name.keyword
{
"properties": {
"my_field": {
"type": "text",
"fielddata": true
}
}
}

#output:#
{
"_index" : "my_index",
"_type" : "_doc",
"_id" : "host.name",
"_version" : 1,
"_seq_no" : 0,
"_primary_term" : 1,
"found" : true,
"_source" : {
"properties" : {
"my_field" : {
"type" : "text",
"fielddata" : true
}
}
}
}
```

And also

```
PUT my_index/_doc/host.name
{
"properties": {
"my_field": {
"type": "text",
"fielddata": true
}
}
}

Output:
{
"_index" : "my_index",
"_type" : "_doc",
"_id" : "host.name",
"_version" : 2,
"result" : "updated",
"_shards" : {
"total" : 2,
"successful" : 1,
"failed" : 0
},
"_seq_no" : 2,
"_primary_term" : 2
}
```

Can any one help me out on my issue.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733898/elasticsearch-group-by-documents-field-and-count-occurences/58734262#58734262